# While scraping with htmlunit why doesn't changing drop down value update the table?

Tags: web-scraping, drop-down-menu, dom-events, htmlunit, yahoo-finance

I am scraping (using htmlunit in Java using Maven in Eclipse IDE) the Yahoo Finance site that shows option contracts (e.g. for Apple stock the url is https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/options?) in tables of "calls" and "puts". Then I save interesting "put" options in an Excel file. It all works fine for the default-date table of put options. When you manually change a drop down select to one of the other dates available, the tables update to the contracts for those dates.  Using Chrome inspect you can see the Javascript that fires to do this update.  Using htmlunit I can: identify the "select" domain node, the available option date values, change the selected date to each of the available values, and prove that I am in fact updating the selected value by printing it to the Eclipse IDE console. I believe that the on change javascript should be triggered automatically by doing this. However, the table of option contracts I retrieve is always (for every available value of option date) the initial table for the default date. As shown, I also tried deliberately executing the Javascript as shown. I tried waiting 5 seconds (also have tried 20 seconds) as shown before refreshing the page and retrieving the table (manually takes about 3 seconds to update). I have also tried not refreshing the page.

Note: The way I retrieve the nodes for the contract date values and for the select seems ugly.  If you use Chrome inspect you'll see that neither of these nodes has an id or a name. They each have a unique class but so far I have only been able to use a class to get the table itself. htmlunit does not seem to have a method to retrieve select node by class, only methods by id or by name. So, I had to select an ancestor node that does have an id and work my way down until I found the list of dates and then went up one level to find a node that could be cast as htmlselect. Only one node could be cast as such, so I am confident this is the select node. Also, I confirmed that I am able to change the selected date value by changing it and then printing the currently selected value to the console.  So, I know I am changing the drop down value.  I have tried various browser emulations available in htmlunit including Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and "best-supported".

After weeks of Googling and trying combinations of tricks, I really am stuck.  Here is my code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient( BrowserVersion.CHROME );
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5 * 1000);
String url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/APPL/options?";
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(url);
Iterable<DomElement> contractDates =  page.getElementById("Col1-1-OptionContracts-Proxy").getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getDomElementDescendants(); //this is the list of option dates in the drop down!!
DomNode theSelector = page.getElementById("Col1-1-OptionContracts-Proxy").getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild();//this gets the drop down node
HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect) theSelector;// "theSelector" is the only node  can be cast as htmlselect; the parent cannot, the child cannot.
                
if (contractDates == null) { System.out.println("***********  Contract Dates not found"); }else 
{   
for (DomElement aContractDate : contractDates) 
{
HtmlOption option = select.getOptionByText(aContractDate.asText());
select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);// confirmed that this selects the option 
page.executeJavaScript("https://s.yimg.com/uc/finance/ddsite/js/vendor.fd8794bfdc89142e2d1.modern.js");//this is from chrome inspect of the event listeners
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5 * 1000);// manually takes about 3 seconds
page = (HtmlPage) page.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage();// to refresh the page
List<HtmlTable> listElement = page.getByXPath("//table[@class='puts W(100%) Pos(r) list-options']");//note that the list retrieved has one element
HtmlTable table = listElement.get(0);// this makes the one element retrieved into a table
List<HtmlTableRow> rows = table.getRows();
                            
//the rest of the code is to retain the rows of the table to the spreadsheet ...
```

Comment: I have found a workaround, maybe the only way to do this.  Manually, on change of date the url is updated to have a date in the form of minutes since 1/1/1970.  Opening a new url constructed with the date in that format works as desired.

Comment: correction: ...a date in the form of seconds since 1/1/1970...